# Problem with doxygen references listing

Tags: c#, doxygen

I'm experimenting with using doxygen on a C# application, however I'm having issues with the REFERENCES_RELATION option. For example, I have the following method:

```
class ControlManager
{

  ...

  public void SendRequest(IRequest req)
  {
    Log.WriteLine("Received request {0}", req.Name);
    requestChain.Handle(req);
  }

  private MessageChain<IRequest> requestChain = ...;
}
```

Which generates the following references line in the html docs:

"References IRequest.Name, ControlManager.requestChain, and Log.WriteLine()."

What I really want it to show is:

"References IRequest.Name, MessageChain.Handle() and Log.Writeline()."

It seems that as Doxygen doesn't see it as a method reference, which means that the MessageChain.Handle docs also doesn't show it as referenced by anything (using the REFERENCED_BY_RELATION option). Is there any way of doing this, or have I missed some key reason why the class field is treated differently from the method parameter?

I'm not sure if it matters but ControlManager and MessageChain are in different namespaces and different projects.

Answer (score 0):

> ControlManager and MessageChain are in different namespaces and different projects.

Do MessageChain and ControlManager classes are parsed using the same doxygen project file ?

If not, as doxygen can't generate a documentation for one of your class, the reference won't be added.

Comment: Yes, sorry I should have clarified that. I've got a single Visual Studio solution and a single doxygen config file which covers the entire solution. Within that solution I have multiple projects, one of which contains ControlManager and another of which contains MessageChain.

Doxygen is generating documentation for the MessageChain class, it just doesn't seem to see the reference between MessageChain and ControlManager.

Comment: maybe you should look for this issue in the doxygen's bugzilla and add it if not exists